# Are there really random fluctuations of particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, elementary-particles

From classical physics, we know that particles are affected by thermal fluctuations. In turn, I wonder if there are any fluctuations of the particles that follow from QM and that are truly random. I know that there’s a term “quantum fluctuations”, but those mean very different thing, judging the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. For example, a quantum harmonic oscillator exhibits [zero point vibration](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hosc4.html).

In fact, quantum randomness is more fundamental than thermal randomness. In principle, if we knew the position and momentum of every particle exactly in classical mechanics, we could compute the entire future trajectory of each particle. We model classical thermal motion as random because of our lack of knowledge of the state of the particles, not because their motion is fundamentally random. In [standard interpretations of] quantum mechanics, there is an intrinsic randomness/non-determinism that is not just due to our lack of knowledge, but is built into the laws of physics at a fundamental level.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! 

Ok, HUP is expresses intrinsic uncertainty - I guess it is what people mean under the lack of realism. 

Two questions follow. 1) How do we calculate those probabilities? We collapse the wavefunction (or decoherence), the result is given by Born's rule. What is the probability that a particle will randomly get some $p+dp$ instead of $p$? 2) Doesn't it actually mean that everything is random, -- thermal motion, browninan motion, every chaotic system, and, eventually, us?

Thanks for the help and sorry for any mess. I just got terribly confused in it.

Comment: @Damcey7 1.) The probability is calculated using the Born rule. For a continuous variable like momentum, the square of the wavefunction $|\psi(p)|^2$ gives you the probability density of finding the particle at $p$. That means the probability of finding the particle from $p$ to $p+dp$ is $|\psi(p)|^2 dp$. 2.) Yes, the Universe is random at a fundamental level, according to quantum mechanics. It is an open question whether that indeterminism matters on large scales, since quantum effects tend to average out in a big and hot macroscopic system like a cat.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I think I got that part. However, aren’t chaotic systems amplify all the minuscule deviations? Of course, we don’t know Lyapunov’s constant for a system like brain, - but theoretically speaking, won’t be it true that, given a sufficient amount of time, every chaotic system is indeterministic thus? The reason I also got concerned is the following paper arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9802054.pdf, which seems quite interesting. It basically implies that any chaotic system is actually indeterministic.

Comment: @Damcey7 I think that's probably right, although as the author says in the conclusion, "It is too early to claim that all the issues arising in the context of the transition from quantum to classical have been settled with the help of decoherence." In other words, we don't understand all the details, so be careful of drawing conclusions that are too strong. However, regardless of quantum mechanics, for all practical purposes chaotic systems are indeterministic, since our ability to predict the system's behavior rapidly deteriorates due to finite measurement error on the initial conditions.